# Webpage elements in code limit

Tags: html, css, browser

Is there a hard (or somewhat-hard) limit on the number of HTML elements (no css, no scripts) a webpage can load on a browser?

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: Anyway, the answers to most of the questions would amount to, "horribly".

Comment: I apologize for asking 8 questions instead of only one. I only did so because I thought of them as related and actually all part of the same basic question. I have amended the original post but in the meantime @abluejelly has been very patient and kind explaining to me in sufficient details the questions and problems I raised. 

Once again, apologies for initially not posting my question correctly. 

Regards,

Georgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a dumb set of questions. Good Code influences speed a lot. Better hardware lowers the layman's ability to distinguish Good from Bad.

A case could be made that we've hit the point in hardware where only extreme cases of Bad code are distinguishable, but that's a discussion for some other time.

Write Good Code.
Don't feed the Dissonance.

---

As for your specific questions...

1) Based on the memory available, yes. As to how many, "yes" is also a good answer, because it's dependent on a lot of things but usually is higher than you'd reasonably hit.

2) Pulling this out of my ass, but generally, the reason your page is slow is (in order of likelyhood):

1. ***Total File Size is Too Damn Big for Available Bandwidth***
2. JS hooks on spammy events (such as scroll; never hook scroll directly)
3. JS that causes repaint and reflow
4. Rendering in general
5. General use of JS
6. JS fetch/parse delay (async/defer and bottom-of-page-load are your friends)
7. CSS parsing & application
8. HTML parsing (assuming not well-formed)
9. HTML parsing (assuming well-formed)

3) Inline styles really don't add much in the grand scheme. Their scope is absurdly small. They honestly contribute more to file size than to parse/apply.

4) Not by much. CSS is declarative and static. Microsoft [tried dynamic for a while](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx) but very quickly realized how bad of an idea that was and killed it. JS is the real bottleneck, not CSS.

5) Depends on hardware and usage. 10 mil blank `<meta />` tags in the head is probably going to do very little. 10 mil `<div>` tags with a ton of supporting CSS and JS, on the other hand, will chug real bad if the machine isn't beefy (and 64bit).
One of the pages at work that is in desperate need of a refactor has around 16800 elements currently, as well as a lot of JS. The page chugs fairly bad at the start, but is reasonably responsive once it's finished loading. Meanwhile, another is sitting around 89.7k. In spite of being orders of magnitude larger, it doesn't have a ton of JS backing it up and many of the elements are (usually) `display:hidden`, so it's actually a lot faster and more responsive of a page (until you hit `ctrl+f`).

6) Not significantly. Some stuff can chug extra hard on one rather than another, but that's usually due to either an impl bug in the browser being proded by some really odd combination or usage of features a web page hit.

7) Better hardware can handle more complex stuff faster, assuming it can be taken advantage of. A 128-core computer can't magically multithread your serial O((n^7)!) script- though the JIT optimizer sure as hell might try.

8) Server Hardware does very little to effect client-side speed unless it's swamped and thus running into the server-side bandwidth limit. Server Hardware does do a lot to effect the speed at which it can produce pages with heavy server-side backend to them. Again, having the server do something that's O((n^7)!) will be slower the worse its hardware is, and that gets compounded significantly by the number of users requesting that operation (assuming you can't/don't lock and return a cached copy of the first request's result).

---

A bit of further reading on [Repaints and Reflows](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/)... The title of the article itself is absurdly bad, but the content is good. In-depth explanations (and even further readings) on repaints and reflows, which, while not quite the same today (8 years later), are still a key concept in page efficiency. Most of these are also still applicable due to how the browser *has* to render some elements (such as tables without `table-layout: fixed;`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer @abluejelly,

Comment: @GeorgiPepelyankov np, thanks for actually accepting it.

Comment: I am a learning developer and am trying to write as clean, correct and structured as possible, thus my questions.

Would you mind me asking a follow-up question:

1. Theoretically, if CSS is very lean and efficient, JS is limited to a bare minimum with maximum optimization and the majority of code is in HTML (<div> and text with CSS attributes applied), would the browser or an average user PC be able to load quickly (hundreds/thousands of) millions of elements?

Your explanations have been very helpful for me to understand how I can write clean code.

Regards,

Georgi

Comment: @GeorgiPepelyankov Probably not quickly. That 89.7k element page I mentioned is 1.6 megs of uncompressed text. Remember, #1 cause of slow is bandwidth requirements. You start throwing images and such in there and you'll slow to a crawl. However, those 89.7k elements (in this case) are enough to list every student in any two of three of our programs and every service they have received from the programs they're in.

Comment: @ablluejelly Could that problem be resolved by caching if most of the elements are "global and shared" and thus can be stored user-side? If the bandwidth issue is by-passed by server-side storing data (if that is possible via caching), would the browser be able to visualize that many elements instantly?

Comment: @GeorgiPepelyankov Minimize the JS you use, yes, but don't shy away from it. Modern CSS3 is powerful, but so is modern JS. Really, it's more don't use JS to do something you can do with CSS unless you have to. A lot of the JS bloat comes from over-reliance on libraries like jQuery, which were originally forged in a time when native JS/CSS solutions required huge amounts of effort. Really, it's just be mindful of what you're doing. If it's presentation-based, it should probably be CSS with at most a little bit of connecting JS to fill any gaps in what CSS can provide.

Comment: @GeorgiPepelyankov Caching is why the internet hasn't slowed to a crawl in spite of the average total size of a webpage (with all linked content) being larger than original Doom. Content Delivery Networks provide caching-friendly references to libraries like jQuery, so multiple sites all hit the same cached file. Even better, extensions like DeCentralEyes for Firefox maintains a multi-CDN cache locally and pseudo-manually bypasses even needing a copy for each CDN (as well as skipping asking if your cache is stale).

Comment: So, if the main coding is 'as-clean-as-possible' HTML & CSS, and efficient & optimized caching via JS is applied, pages with millions and potentially billions of elements could be loaded quickly on user-side (both on desktop and mobile) as long as the cache is properly controlled. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: @GeorgiPepelyankov Kind of? You wouldn't really be loading all of the elements at once. Usually you'd use some form of smart "infinite scroll" which only loads elements as they're needed, and tosses them when they're not needed any more. Most scrolling is downwards, which requires minimal reflow to add more to, hence why most of Social Media "grows" your scroll bar when you get towards the bottom, and it doesn't drag you into performance hell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and your help! This information has opened my eyes on how to structure my website before I even begin coding. Could you recommend some "must read" materials on the topics of page load limitations, working with high numbers of elements and best practices in caching? I've googled the topics of all of my questions and never really found an answer which tackles the problem from the perspective I'm looking at.

Comment: @GeorgiPepelyankov I added one link, talking about repaints/reflows which are the biggest performance hog of JS. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of things bookmarked (unless you need some ASP.NET or TSQL tomes lol). A lot of efficiency is simply being mindful of what you're *really* making the browser do to get to where you want.

Comment: thank you once again, I have bookmarked it and will further read into repaints/reflows as I think smart caching will be vital for what I'm currently working on.